# My asterisk server can't read extensions.conf

Tags: asterisk

I've installed asterisk on ubuntu 22 on virtualbox everything is ok when voip call comes to my server it says me :

```
rejected because extension not found in context 'default'.
```

my sip.conf file :

```
[1060] ; This will be WebRTC client
type=friend
username=1060 ; The Auth user for SIP.js
host=dynamic ; Allows any host to register
secret=password ; The SIP Password for SIP.js
encryption=yes ; Tell Asterisk to use encryption for this peer
avpf=yes ; Tell Asterisk to use AVPF for this peer
icesupport=yes ; Tell Asterisk to use ICE for this peer
context=default ; Tell Asterisk which context to use when this peer is dialing
directmedia=no ; Asterisk will relay media for this peer
transport=udp,ws ; Asterisk will allow this peer to register on UDP or WebSockets
force_avp=yes ; Force Asterisk to use avp. Introduced in Asterisk 11.11
dtlsenable=yes ; Tell Asterisk to enable DTLS for this peer
dtlsverify=no ; Tell Asterisk to not verify your DTLS certs
dtlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem ; Tell Asterisk where your DTLS cert file   is
dtlsprivatekey=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem ; Tell Asterisk where your DTLS private key is
dtlssetup=actpass ; Tell Asterisk to use actpass SDP parameter when setting up DTLS
```

and my extensions.conf file :

```
[default]
 exten => 1060,1,Dial(SIP/1060) ; Dialing 1060 will call the SIP client registered to 1060
```

Even i remove the extionsions.conf i dont get an error

Comment: The pbx_config.so  is  Not Running what can i possibly do

Comment: Now it's running and same error

Comment: CLI> dialplan show 1060@default
[ Context 'default' created by 'pbx_config' ]
  '1060' =>         1. Dial(SIP/1060)                             [custom_extension.conf:2]

-= 1 extension (1 priority) in 1 context. =-

Comment: now it shows me the context is registered but it wont work